# Magento template <a href=""></a> not interpreted

Tags: magento2, email-templates

I created a custom form to allow people to ask a catalog, the form works, but when I try to send a mail confirmation to the customer with the catalog link, I see the html tag on the mail.

[image]

How fix that ?

```
$message_customer = __('Votre demande de catalogue a bien été prise en compte. Vous pouvez visualiser votre catalogue <a target="_blank" href="%1%2">ici</a>.',
    $mediaBaseUrl,
    'catalogue.pdf'
);
```

and the template is

```
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="6" valign="top" style="font-size:12px;padding:7px 9px 9px 9px;border:1px solid #EAEAEA;">
            {{var message_customer}}
        </td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use it like this in you email template file

```
<a href={{var yourUrl}} target="__blank"> Test </a>
```

**Hope it Helps.**